# getElementsByTagName gives us the same result for IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

We are using the getElementsByTagName function to find out domnodes present in the article.

We found that IE and Firefox give different result for broken tag as below.

e.g. 
`<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Bypass HTML tags</ a> &nbsp;`  Complete 2  Fails

In IE :
for above example we will get two nodes 'A' and '/'.

In firefox
for above example we will get one node 'A'.

Both browsers should give same Dom elements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why should browsers give the same results when they are trying to recover from bad code?

Answer (score 3):

`</ a>` is not valid (X)HTML. You want `</a>`

Comment: +1 This is correct, when you close a tag like this in IE, it treats it as a `</>` tag e.g. `</ a="">`.  Ridiculous, I know.

Comment: Actually, IE got this one right... that's how it should be interpreted in HTML, just as in `<br />` the `/` is really a throw-away attribute... in regular xml (not xhtml) you could write `<br/>`, but for html compatibility you need the space so older browsers will treat the slash as an attribute.